# Java Mail NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler

Tags: ubuntu, spring-mvc, jetty, javamail

Ни как не поборется эта ошибка.

в pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Разные версии пробовал, делаю WAR кидаю в томкат на ноуте все работает, почта отправляется. Кидаю этот же варник на сервер со свежеустановленными ubuntu 16, java 9, jetty 9 письма отправляться не хотят, получаю ошибку:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
```

Эта либа также есть WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar

Чего оно ругается (уже мозг проело)?

Установил на сервере Tomcat9, все робит, придется отказаться от Jetty из-за не понятных багов.